# Когда в правилах было закреплено только слитное написание причинного союз «оттого что»?

Tags: орфография, союзы, слитно-раздельно

**О ситуации в целом**

1. В своде 1956 года **перечислен союз ОТТОГО ЧТО** среди других составных союзов.
2. До этого периода причинный союз ОТТОГО ЧТО писался, как слитно, так и раздельно (частотность 6427:2375).
3. Затем в течение 20 лет две формы сохранялись, но частотность **изменялась незначительно** (1345:415). Такое впечатление, что строгой регламентации не было и тогда.
4. В настоящее время  раздельное написание ОТ ТОГО ЧТО встречается **достаточно часто.**

**И вопросы:**

1. **Когда и кем** в правилах  было дано **четкое предписание** относительно слитного написания причинного союза ОТТОГО ЧТО?
2. Нужно ли все причинные союзы писать **одинаково без учета семантических оттенков** (раздельное написание могло бы отличать конкретную причину-предмет от ситуации в целом).

Примеры

Однажды ночью я проснулся **от того, что** около меня никого нет. [Ю. О. Домбровский. (1943-1958)]

В голове у меня всё вертелось, и главным образом **от того, что** окружающий мир меня волновал чем-то. [М. А. Булгаков. Записки покойника (Театральный роман) (1936-1937)]

… вот уже вечер, а чувство радости **от того, что** я встретила тебя, не растворилось, не иссякло. [А. С. Эфрон. Письма Б. Л. Пастернаку (1948-1959)]

― Я получил глубокое удовлетворение **от того, что** портрет понравился и всем нашим. [Зоя Масленикова. Близкие Бориса Пастернака (1968-2000)

То ли **от скромности**, то ли **от того, что** он был прав. [Андрей Битов. Обоснованная ревность (1960-1999)]

Проснулся я на полу под телефоном **от того, что** в дверях настойчиво зашебуршился ключ… [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)

И Куренкова передернуло **от того, что** Шурочка прочла его мысли, как свои. [Владимир Маканин. Антилидер (1970-1990)]

.. ответил он, почти физически страдая **от того, что** она сейчас уйдет и смотрит так враждебно, вернее, старается совсем не смотреть на него. [П. Л. Проскурин. Исход. Части I-II (1967)

Answer (score 1):

Когда составной союз распределяется по предложениям, то он превращается либо в предлог ‟от”, местоимение ‟того”, союз ‟что”; либо в наречие ‟оттого”, союз ‟что”. Если он распределяется в три слова, среди которых есть предлог, то этот предлог должен сочетаться с предшествующим глаголом (в подобном причинном значении). Например, глагол ‟приходить” не сочетается с предлогом ‟от”. Нельзя говорить: ‟Я пришел в больницу от головной боли”. Глагол ‟пришел” не сочетается с предлогом ‟от”, поэтому нельзя писать: ‟... пришел от того ...”. Если глагол сочетается с предлогом ‟от”, то пишите как хотите. Каждый глагол в приведенных вами предложениях сочетается с предлогом ‟от”.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но мне кажется, что дело не в этом.  Слитная форма письма  формально различает разные по структуре предложения.  Сравнить:  Он огорчился от того,  что услышал.  Он огорчился оттого,  что услышал это. В одном случае у нас союзное слово, а в другом - союз.   Но почему эта формальность должна однозначно влиять на смысловые и стилистические оттенки речи?  Такая формализация не всегда уместна. Например: То ли от скромности, то ли от того, что он был прав. (Андрей Битов). Здесь раздельное написание мне кажется более уместным.

Comment: Не понимаю, что значит ‟разные по структуре”. Нет, в обоих случаях союзное слово. Но семантическая разница действительно есть: ‟Он огорчился от того, что услышал это” = ”Он огорчился из-за содержания услышанного”, а ‟Он огорчился оттого, что услышал это” = ‟Он огорчился из-за того факта, что услышывание произошло”. В некоторых редких ситуация одно предложение применимо, а другое нет и наоборот.